# What is the cheapest car in game that is easily available?

Tags: achievements, gran-turismo-7

For the sake of achievements, which I won't list to avoid spoilers, I'm curious what the cheapest car is that is available. By easily available I mean it should be for sale contineously or at least at on a somewhat daily basis.

I know the used cars available will change, so maybe that's not useful unless the same cars appear regularly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the cheapest car in the game is a Honda Fit at $16,800

Otherwise, if the go-kart counts, that's $10,000. But I'm not sure if that counts towards the trophy.

Comment: I bought 10 carts and can confirm this counts towards the trophy.